# Applying Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on multiplication of functions

Tags: definite-integrals

I gotta differentiate this, and I don't know if my answer is correct

$$ F(x) = \int_0^{f(x)} f(u)g(u) \, du = $$

Should it be

$$F'(x) = f(f(x)) f'(x) g(f(x)) f'(x)$$

And if it is or not correct, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Leibniz rule for differentiating under the integral sign,

$f(f(x))g(f(x))*f'(x)$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: 's Sir, where did you learn Leibniz Rule for differentiating? And in Wich book I can learn about it? Thank you

Comment: I think it's in Michael Spivak Calculus book

Comment: sir, I tried it but I can't see how you did it.

Comment: The function were integrating is independent of $x$, so the term with the partial derivative is just $0$.

$b(x) = f(x)$, $a(x) = 0$. This means that $\frac{d}{dx}b(x) = f'(x)$, $\frac{d}{dx}a(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. Denote
$$
G(x) = \int_0^{x} f(u)g(u) \, du
$$
Then we have
$$
G'(x) = f(x)g(x).
$$
Can you now apply a chain rule to find a derivative of 
$$
F(x) = G(f(x))?
$$